# CSS to stretch span to height of container

Tags: css, height, html

I've set two span elements side by side with a separating border being applied to one of the spans. The problem occurs when one span has more lines than the other. If the span with less content is the one which has the border applied to it, the border doesn't stretch to the bottom of the container.

I've tried adding height and min-height elements to the span, the containing div, the HTML and body tags in various combinations with no success.

Here is the sample HTML:

```
<div class="newspecs">
    <div class="ns_row_type_2">
        <span class="ns_field_name">Flash Exposure Compensation</span>
        <span class="ns_field_value">+/- EV<br>more text<br>more text<br>more text<br>more text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the applicable CSS:

```
.newspecs div {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.newspecs span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.ns_row_type_1,
.ns_row_type_2 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.ns_row_type_1 {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.ns_field_name {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 3px;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
.ns_field_value {
    width: 280px;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

The full CSS and HTML is at:

http://yazminmedia.com/clients/IR/test.htm

Anyone have an idea of what is going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Span is an inline element and thus its height is only as much as it's contents. Would this be easier to do with tables?

Comment: Which would you prefer: table base layouts (IE6 compatible) or CSS3 (IE9+)

Comment: try using table.It might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be using a HTML TABLE here as this is a table of data that you are trying to display.

However as a nasty hack, change **ns_field_value** to...

> `.ns_field_value {width: 280px; padding: 3px; margin-left:-4px; border-left:1px solid #fff}`

This just adds a border-left to the field value 'cell' and then does a -4px margin so that the borders overlap appearing to create a single border.

Comment: I would have used a table, but this is what I was asked for.

Comment: No worries. And Ive upvoted Petah's answer as Option 1 is similar (but with floats) and he/she has given some valid alternatives :)

Comment: Ah yes, I was moving in the direction of using Option 1 provided, but when I saw the additional blank divs added just for clearing, I chose yours as the lesser of two evil. In any case, I had upvoted Petah's answer too as I appreciated the additional options and the use of jsfiddle to see the results all in one place. :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Option 1: Floats, extra border, and 1px negative margin

- http://jsfiddle.net/95uMq/

Option 2: CSS3

- http://jsfiddle.net/95uMq/1/

Option 3: Table based Layout

- http://jsfiddle.net/95uMq/2/